# Lua Server Client Chat Example

Tags: server, lua, client

I am trying to create a simple chat application with lua following are my files

```
-- load namespace
local socket = require("socket")
-- create a TCP socket and bind it to the local host, at any port
local server = assert(socket.bind("*", 0))
-- find out which port the OS chose for us
local ip, port = server:getsockname()
-- print a message informing what's up
print("Please telnet to localhost on port " .. port)
print("After connecting, you have 10s to enter a line to be echoed")
-- loop forever waiting for clients

local client = server:accept()
client:setoption("keepalive", true)
while 1 do  
  local line, err = client:receive()

    print(line .. 'sent by client')
  if not err then 
    client:send(line .. "\n") 
  else
    print('error')
    print(err)
  end
end
client:close()
```

server.lua

```
local host, port = "127.0.0.1",arg[1]
local socket = require("socket")
local tcp = assert(socket.tcp())
tcp:connect(host, port);
--note the newline below
tcp:send("hello world\n");

while true do
    local s, status, partial = tcp:receive()
    print(s or partial)
    print("enter message to send")
    local message = io.read()
    print("sending message" .. message)
    tcp:send(message);
    if status == "closed" then break end


end
tcp:close()
```

client.lua

Now I cannot get my head around that the server does not receive after the first hello world and how do i connect another client while the server is already connected to the client, does lua offer any callback for receive or connection established?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never send any actual end of line to the server, after the first line. Since `message` will not contain any line end, `client:receive()` will wait for the end forever (because it reads a *line* from the socket).

You can try calling `server:accept()` multiple times to wait for a new client. Combined with a timeout and coroutines, you can serve multiple clients.

Comment: it seems server:accept and client:receive() both are blocking calls so what if my code is waiting for server:accept() and a new message from old client comes in?

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar You need some kind of coroutine scheduler that tries reading from clients or accepting new ones with a timeout and sends the results to corresponding routines.